# Windows symbolic link ASP.NET app repository

Tags: asp.net

We are hosting huge app for our cutomers. There are diffrent configuration and contents (images, user files). But the core code, directories structure, databse scheme is this same for every client.

I'm looking for a way to create one core code repository, so all clientes will use it. We do updates often, so this will make our live easyer.

The idea is to create the repo and In clients directories create just symbolic links to that repo direcories: bin, App_Resources, Css, SystemImages etc.

Is this a good idea? Will ASP.NET MVC app handle this correctly, or I've to add some code for it handle the 'virtual direcotories'?

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest** that you take a look **Single-tenant** and **Multi-tenant** applications even if you say that your code base is the same for every one.

[Here is a nice Multi-Tenancy ASP.NET example](https://github.com/zowens/Multi-tenancy-Sample)

**I would also suggest** that you check http://appHarbour.com as you can easily push changes from your master repository to appHarbour using Git or Mercurial.

Regarding your exact question, I also keep static files in a custom scheme under **Amazon S3**, so each client can upload there own files, plus the ones I have and all is based on a single location that does not put more resources just to delivery static files.

You can see [my live web application](http://eu-1.julekal.dk/callme_demo/) using this technique checking the *View Source*.

Comment: ok, but I don't want to use repostiory update and commit and going to multi-tendent looks like a lot of job for us. It's great idea do :). So may anyone tell me what are pro and ops for windows symbolic directories?